# Html table breaking row when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, css-tables

I'm currently having some issues with a table I'm trying to print, if it has more than one page, on the page break, the table row in there is being cropped. I've already tried using `table { page-break-inside:auto }` and `tr { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }`, but neither worked.

It may be something in conflict with my css?

Here's the Jsfiddle with it: [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/LL4yte8u/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your CSS to this

```
 @media print {

  table.report { page-break-after:auto }
  table.report tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  table.report td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  table.report thead { display:table-header-group }
  table.report tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
 }
```

and also remove all extra

```
<tbody>...</tbody>
```

, you should have only one

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

and all tr between that.

that should work for you.

ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the css to the one you posted and added `height: 100%;` to the css. It worked on Windows but on Mac, in the same browsers the crop is happening out of the place like in this image: [link](http://imgur.com/a/7imm6)

Comment: which browsers have you tested? can you take a screenshot and put it here as a link?

Comment: I've managed to fix it by using the A4 sheet size on width and height on the `@media print` css. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In my case I did not need to defind the breaking for `td`, it was just enough doing it for `tr`

Comment: That doesn't work.