# CSS page-break-before not working on table row

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a HTML table like so:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="page-break">
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What I am trying to do is apply a page-break before the third row when printing.

I have applied the following CSS:

```
@media print {
            tr.page-break {
                page-break-before: always;
            }
}
```

Which did absolutely nothing, then I applied display: block to this CSS code like so:

```
@media print {
            tr.page-break {
                page-break-before: always;
                display: block;
            }
}
```

It doesn't do the page breaks and it also messes up my table when printing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: page-break-before => You cannot use this property on an empty <div> or on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: @user979331 - the edit that I put in the answer is the most accredited solution to this problem, it's apparently a known problem that many have encountered with no better solution available as yet. Could you accept the answer? Happy holidays..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using print media queries, it's best to add `!important` to the styles specified within the print media query (it's one of the few times when adding `!important` is advocated!)

Try:

```
@media print {
        tr.page-break {
            page-break-before:always!important;
        }
 }
```

and see how you go.. Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

Adjust your CSS to include the following:

```
 @media print {
  table.report { page-break-after:auto }
  table.report tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  table.report td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  table.report thead { display:table-header-group }
  table.report tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
 }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126325/1675954) Thank you [Majid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1921541/majid)!

Phew!

Comment: @user979331 also, ensure the class is defined in the main CSS. You could have .pbrk{} (empty class) or you could instead just add a small margin-top ( 1px or 2px or something). I'd go for the latter

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046834/page-break-before-table-row which gives a comprehensive explanation . (basically it says that there has to be 2 divs in the table row, even if one is empty, and put a page-break-before on the second one) The other question it links to has another answer with 97 votes! You could try that.. Curious that it's such a big issue..

Comment: That kinda works, its does the page breaks, but it creates a very very long table cell with a border, it will show the first two rows, do a page break, then on the second page have a very long cell with a border (just one cell) and then do the next rows.

Comment: @user979331 if it's only showing 2 rows, I say put page-break-after? (instead of page-break-before?) if your table has a border, that would have the effect of making it appear long, depending on the height of the table rows..

Answer (score 2):

Try below: No need for @media print

```
 table tr.page-break{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-before: always;
 }
```

you may need to specify width for the columns.

OR

with @media print

```
 @media print {
    .page-break  { page-break-before: always; }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this in Chrome and Safari and it does not work